# Trying to upload a dockerfile to aws ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to upload a dockerfile to AWS's ECR Service.

But when I issue the command

```
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2
```

I get an error saying the host is down

```
'Connection aborted.', error(64, 'Host is down')
```

I'm using aws on a Mac

```
aws-cli/1.15.8 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/17.5.0 botocore/1.10.8
```

I tried to install python3 as indicated in the aws-docs, but it fails miserably with several errors. Python is always pointing to the Apple default install (in /usr/bin/python).

I tried about a dozen solutions from the web (including installing it via homebrew) - none of them helped.

I had to download the aws installer directly from amazon's servers, which worked:

```
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Any ideas?

[EDIT]

I'm actually still interested, why this all happens, but in the meantime, I abandoned AWS and switched to IBM-Bluemix. Deploying a Node-JS app was a breeze and took 5 minutes.

Comment: Check you firewall settings

Comment: I don't have a firewall